# Why createError is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I'm trying to get my code to return me to my flights detail page with a controller function. My routes for the `createTicket` and new ticket are working and render the create ticket form but once I press the `create ticket` in the browser I am getting a `createError` is not defined.

I have checked my routes and controllers and It seems that all of it is correct and working except when I hit the create ticket button it send me to the `createError`. It seems to be that when my page is rendering out it is trying to render the path `/flights//tickets` and I don't have this defined anywhere in my code.

This is my code.

```js
async function createTicket(req, res) {
  const flightId = req.params.flightId;
  try {
    const ticket = await Ticket.create({
      ...req.body,
      flight: flightId,
    });
    res.redirect(`/flights/${flightId}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
}
module.exports = {
  createTicket,
};
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const ticketsController = require("../controllers/ticketsController");
router.post("/flights/:flightId/tickets", ticketsController.createTicket);
module.exports = router;
```